# How to pass parameters through components

Tags: aem

I have a component that instances 3 or more components.
I need to pass one parameter for each of his sons
Is there a way to do it?

For example a code like this:

```
<cq:include path="x" resourceType="compo">
<parameter....>
</cq:include>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is pretty easy solution:

1. In your main component define variable with request **scope**
   (`<c:set var="param" value="10" scope="request" />`).
2. In component,
   which you include several times in main one you van use variable
   `${param}`

Comment: @user2509645 Then can you please accept an answer to help other users to find answer to similar question?