# Include action in AEM

Tags: jsp, aem

I keep getting "resource not found" when trying to use the include action in AEM 6.0.  Have tried giving a fuller path, and the relative path to the file in the same directory as the caller:

```
<jsp:include path="/apps/something/components/something/a.jsp" />
<jsp:include path="a.jsp" />
```

I could use the directive, but I assume it's preferable to use "jsp:param" over polluting the request object?

Have double checked the full path above... any ideas how I might debug this?

Comment: Refer [CQ includes](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQIncludes.html)

Comment: So no proper parameter passing? Just dumping everything into the request?  Also no mention of jsp:include as an option? jsp:include stands out as better nomenclature?

Comment: Have not used jsp:include in CQ components, cannot confirm on that. I would suggest to search more or check with Day Care support, if anyone on SO knows this, they would reply as most of people are #SOReadyToHelp :). Found one [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320814/how-to-pass-parameters-through-components), see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

In AEM I've never used a jsp:include. There are better options for this in AEM.

If it is an include before compile time you can use the same as is used for the global.jsp:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
```

If you are including AEM components or just another JSP with its own context, you either use `cq:include` or `sling:include`, the latter allows additional parameters and lets you override some request scope variables:

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

or

```
<cq:include script="body.jsp" />
```

A documentation regarding the tag libraries in AEM can be found here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/platform/taglib.html